# Fun with Dita_scans: NameError: name 'outputclass' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, xml, error-handling, command-prompt, dita

So I work with python 3.8 and command prompt to create Dita_scans. This is a tool you rely on that locates errors in your written documents (such as missing short descriptions and titles that don't match up with their filename counterparts)

In order to create a dita_scan the command prompt has to look like this: python -m dita_scan -r C:\Users\sm041849\Documents\Dita -i ca-mainframe-software\database-management\ca-log-analyzer-for-db2-for-z-os\baseline-20\ca-log-analyzer-for-db2-for-z-os-20.ditamap -o C:\Users\sm041849\Documents\Dita\ca-mainframe-software\database-management\ca-log-analyzer-for-db2-for-z-os\baseline-20 --scandepth 2

However when I input that command I repeatedly receive an error labeled- NameError: name 'outputclass'is not defined.

Does anyone have any insight they can share on this topic?

Comment: Sounds like you might have a DTD problem. The DITA OT can't find the DTD for some topic, it might have a bad DOCTYPE. You can get more data by adding --verbose to your command line.

Comment: Please explain more about "dita_scan". As far as I know, It is not common program or utility in DITA publishing.